# Nested accordion menu expanded on page load with current classes highlighting the nav item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an accordion menu for my navigation that has nested items inside a few list items. (I know I know accordian is spelled wrong).

```
<div id="accordian-nav">
        <ul>
            <?php foreach($menu->items() as $item): ?>
                <?php if(empty($item->permissions) || Auth::instance()->logged_in($item->permissions)): ?>
                    <?php if($item->children()): ?>
                    <li>
                        <h3 class="nav-h3"><span class=""></span><?php echo $item->name; ?></h3>
                        <ul>
                            <?php foreach($item->children() as $subitem): ?>
                                <?php if(empty($subitem->permissions) || Auth::instance()->logged_in($subitem->permissions)): ?>
                                    <?php if($subitem->children()): ?>
                                    <li class="podcast-name podcast-options"><a href="<?php echo $subitem->link; ?>"><span class="nav-dash-arrow">&nbsp;</span><?php echo $subitem->name; ?></a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <?php foreach($subitem->children() as $subsubitem): ?>
                                                <?php if(empty($subsubitem->permissions) || Auth::instance()->logged_in($subsubitem->permissions)): ?>
                                                <li><a href="<?php echo $subsubitem->link; ?>"<?php if($tab==$subsubitem->tab) echo ' class="current sub-current"'; ?>><?php echo $subsubitem->name; ?></a></li>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                    <li><a href="<?php echo $subitem->link; ?>"<?php if($tab==$subitem->tab) echo ' class="current sub-current"'; ?>><?php echo $subitem->name; ?></a></li>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <?php else: ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>" title="<?php echo $item->name; ?>"<?php if($tab==$item->tab) echo ' class="current"'; ?>><h3 class="nav-h3"><?php echo $item->name; ?></h3></a></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

My nested list expands the way I want it to except that I need it to be expanded and showing the nested list items when those pages are loaded.

Here is my jquery for the styling.  A class of "current" is being added via PHP.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#accordion-nav h3").click(function(){
        $("#accordion-nav ul ul").slideUp();
        if(!$(this).next().is(":visible"))
            {
            $(this).next().slideDown();
                $('#accordion-nav ul li:hover').css('margin-right', '0px');
                    $(this).css('background', '#1F89C6');
                    $(this).css('border-bottom', 'none');
                    $(this).css('border-left', '6px solid #1F89C6');            
            } 
        })
});
```

Here is my jQuery for the accordion nested list items.  When the parent ul li is clicked the nested items show.  This works great although I am aware the jQuery is being repeated which is poor technique.

```
<script>
    $('.podcast-name').on('click', function(){
        $('.podcast-name > ul').slideToggle('slow');
    });
</script>

<script>
    $('.podcast-two').on('click', function(){
    $('.podcast-two > ul').slideToggle('slow');
    });
</script>

<script>
    $('.podcast-three').on('click', function(){
    $('.podcast-three > ul').slideToggle('slow');
    });
</script>
```

Now, I can't figure out how to expand this list **on page load** and show the active nav item. This is my attempt.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#accordian-nav li h3").load(function(){
   if ($('#accordian-nav ul li a.current').is(':visible')) 
   {
            $(this).next().slideDown();
   }
   });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: You should made a fiddel and add the CSS styles, which are quite important in this case. You just need to add a class to the element for the current page which overwrites the style `display:none` of the class to make it visible.

Comment: for reference: fiddle = http://jsfiddle.net/. on another note, what exactly are you attempting with the onclick(slideup/slidedown)?

Comment: Be careful ! :visible is a tricky one sometimes :: visibility:hidden will return true for :visible http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/